# How to check on client if image was correctly loaded

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

In my laravel 5.8 / bootstrap 4.3 / vuejs "^2.5.17" / "jquery": "^3.4.1" app I read data from remote web 
service and any rows can have link to image, so in my template
I make :

```
<td class="align-middle" style="width: 180px" v-if="nextSearchResult.PictureUrl">
    <img :src="nextSearchResult.PictureUrl" alt="" class=" mx-auto d-block" style="width:100px; height: auto; ">
</td>
```

But when nextSearchResult.PictureUrl is filled but has invalid url or some urls return “access denied” I got empty block on my image.
Sure, I can check on server when all data are red, but such checking can add a lot of time to working of my remote request.
If there is a way to make this check on client with JS/vuejs/jquery ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td v-if="nextSearchResult.PictureUrl" class="align-middle" style="width: 180px">
    <img :src="nextSearchResult.PictureUrl" alt="" class=" mx-auto d-block" style="width:100px; height: auto; ">
</td>
<td v-else class="align-middle" style="width: 180px">
 <div>Sorry we are having trouble loading this image</div>
</td>
```

If you want to see in your code, simply write a computed property:

```
computed: {
   isPicture(){
         const value =  this.nextSearchResult.PictureUrl
         if (value === some option I dont like){
         return false
    }
    return true
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, if I put my question unclear . In my case nextSearchResult.PictureUrl HAS value, but invalid, as nonexisting url or access deny to this ur.

Comment: I am not sure what "some option I dont like" is here? I search method like "CheckOnClientIfValidImageLoaded" ? Are there ?

Comment: if nextSearchResult.PictureUrl HAS a value as you write BUT not one that will display the picture that is an option you "don't like" then you handle that case by returning false and displaying the text I put above. If it does display the image the computed property evaluates to true and displays the image.